# Find value in dropdown and then select it through jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to find out a value which is present in dropdown list and then select that value as selected object in dropdownlist. Im using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select the option with a value you can use

```
$("#dropdownid").val(yourvalue);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb3br/)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Rahul's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323577/find-value-in-dropdown-and-then-select-it-through-jquery/4323587#4323587), if you want to select it by its index, you can do...

```
$('select#my')[0].selectedIndex = 5;
```

Comment: if you are using an id selector then theres no need for that element selector.

Comment: @rahul Depends. This JavaScript could be on two pages - one which has a `#my` as a `select`, and one which `#my` could be not a select. Edge case, I know. I just put it there for an example :)